# Can we ignore the scalar field (dilaton) term in the Polyakov sigma-model action when deriving the classical equations of motion?

Tags: string-theory, sigma-models, equations-of-motion

I have the full Polyakov sigma model action:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&S=S_P + S_B + S_\Phi = \\
&- {1 \over 4 \pi \alpha'} \Big[ \int_\Sigma d^2\sigma \sqrt{-g} g^{ab} \partial_a X^\mu \partial_b X^\nu G_{\mu\nu}(X)\, + \\
&+\epsilon^{ab} B_{\mu\nu}(X) \partial_a X^\mu \partial_b X^\nu \, +\alpha'\Phi(X) R^{(2)}(\sigma) \Big] \,.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

and I want to derive the classical equations of motion by varying $X \mapsto X + \delta X$. I am confused as to what to do with the last term. It is of a higher power of $\alpha '$, so I am thinking it can just be ignored, as it's variation will be of a higher order. Is this thinking correct?

Does this question even make sense, as I'm trying to derive classical equations from a sigma-model, which as far as I have seen, is used when quantizing the string?

Comment: Under $X \to X + \delta X$, we have $\Phi(X) \to \Phi(X+\delta X) = \Phi(X) + \delta X^\mu \partial_\mu \Phi(X)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings in strong gravitational fields - Gary T. Horowitz and Alan R. Steif, Phys. Rev. D 42, 1950 confirms the argument in the question:

"For the remainder of this section we
consider a purely classical string. Since the dilaton term
is multiplied by $\alpha'$, it is a quantum correction and does
not directly affect the motion of a classical string."